# many-to-one, all-delete orphan, set property to null but entity not deleted

Tags: nhibernate

Using NHibernate v3.0. I have a class similar to this:

```
class Foo
{
  bool barActive;
  Bar bar;
}
```

The Bar instance is managed entirely internally to Foo:

1. when "barActive" is true, "bar" is set to a Bar instance.
2. when "barActive" is set to false, the "bar" field is set to null.

Foo.bar is mapped like so:

```
<many-to-one name="bar" column="BarId" cascade="all-delete-orphan" unique="true" />
```

However, when "bar" is set to null, it does not delete the Bar record in the database. Bar is an inherited class that is used elsewhere as well, so I can't just make this field a component.

I would have expected the "unique" constraint + "delete-orphan" to handle this. Am I missing something, or can NHibernate not handle this transparently? If it can't, it seems my only option is to raise an event so a higher-level scope can call ISession.Delete(bar).

Comment: a `many-to-one` mapping doesn't have an option for all-delete-orphan in cascade. Only `all|none|save-update|delete`. See here http://www.nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#mapping-declaration-manytoone

Comment: Then why is the mapping accepted by NHibernate without an error? In any case, do you have a way to accomplish what I'm looking for?

Comment: as far as I can tell there is no way for NHibernate to automatically delete an orphan for a `many-to-one` relationship as there is no check for that in the code. It will cascade the other 4 as mentioned though. There is this jira ticket http://216.121.112.228/browse/NH-1262 which I think is related, but you can open up another one specifically for your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have a workaround, that will automatically delete the orphan. I believe it should work for NHibernate version 3 and above. It uses an interceptor - basically an object that handles various session-related events. When it detects the update operation on `Foo`, it will add an explicit delete for the orphaned `Bar`.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using NHibernate;
using NHibernate.Type;

class Interceptor : EmptyInterceptor
{
    private ISession _session;
    private Bar _barOrphan;

    public override void SetSession(ISession session)
    {
        base.SetSession(session);
        _session = session;
    }

    public override bool OnFlushDirty(object entity, object id, object[] currentStates, object[] previousStates, string[] propertyNames, IType[] types)
    {
        if (entity.GetType() != typeof(Foo)) return;

        for (var i = 0; i < propertyNames.Length; i++)
        {
            if (!StringComparer.Ordinal.Equals(propertyNames[i], "bar")) continue;

            object previousState = previousStates[i];
            if (currentStates[i] != previousState)
            {
                _barOrphan = (Bar) previousState;
            }
            break;
        }
    }

    public override void PostFlush(ICollection entities)
    {
        if (_barOrphan == null) return;

        _session.Delete(_barOrphan);
        _barOrphan = null;

        _session.Flush();
    }
}
```

Now, when opening your NHibernate session, you have to use one of the overloads that accepts an interceptor instance as an argument, e.g.

```
using (ISession session = YourSessionFactoryGoesHere.OpenSession(new Interceptor()))
{
    ...
}
```

Please note that this is just a draft, to explain the concept (I hope I did not screw up the code as I was rewriting it ;-). In a real usage scenario, you may have to deal with possible multiple orphans created in one unit of work (event on the same entity, e.g. `Foo` could have `bar1` and `bar2`!), so instead of a single `_barOrphan` member you will need a queue of the delete actions to be executed in `PostFlush()`. Instead of hard-coding the types of the involved classes and the name of the property `bar`, you will want to use generics and a property selector (e.g. `PropertySelector.GetPropertyName<Foo>(foo => foo.bar)`, see [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10224119/get-property-type-by-memberexpression). DB constraint could be a problem, moving the delete operation to `Interceptor.PreFlush()` might help, but I did not test it. Don't forget about the performance impact (e.g. `OnFlushDirty()` is invoked for each updated entity, so don't make it a bottleneck).