# Get property type by MemberExpression

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, properties, expression

I ask similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10222783/get-property-name-and-type-by-pass-it-directly)
, assume this type:

```
 public class Product {

public string Name { get; set; }
public string Title { get; set; }
public string Category { get; set; }
public bool IsAllowed { get; set; }

}
```

and this one that use `MemberExpression` :

```
public class HelperClass<T> {

    public static void Property<TProp>(Expression<Func<T, TProp>> expression) {

        var body = expression.Body as MemberExpression;

        if(body == null) throw new ArgumentException("'expression' should be a member expression");

        string propName = body.Member.Name;
        Type proptype = null;

    }

}
```

I use it like this:

```
HelperClass<Product>.Property(p => p.IsAllowed);
```

in `HelperClass` I just need property name(in this example `IsAllowed`) and property type (in this example `Boolean`) So I can get property name but I can't get property type. I see the property type in debugging as following picture shown:

[image]

So what is your suggestion to get property type?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Try casting `body.Member` to a `PropertyInfo`

```
public class HelperClass<T>
{
    public static void Property<TProp>(Expression<Func<T, TProp>> expression)
    {
        var body = expression.Body as MemberExpression;

        if (body == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("'expression' should be a member expression");
        }

        var propertyInfo = (PropertyInfo)body.Member;

        var propertyType = propertyInfo.PropertyType;
        var propertyName = propertyInfo.Name;
    }
}
```